# Apache proxypass directive does not recover quickly

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am using this "simple" apache ProxyPass directive.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On    
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ServerName my.name.org
</VirtualHost>
```

This works well.  If the internal server listening on port 3000 "goes down" temporarily, and I make a request to "my.name.org", a 503 is returned as expected.  However, even if the internal server comes up, subsequent request to "my.name.org" result in a 503 for "some period of time" (whereas, if no initial request that generates a 503 occurs, no subsequent requests work as normal).  Is there some value I can adjust to make it so that after bringing the internal server back up, apache will notice it and use it more quickly?

Comment: Have you checked the network traffic to ensure there is no local caching?

Comment: It's a pretty clean/fresh box so I don't think it's using any kind of other internal caching, but who knows, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a connection to a back-end server generates and error (default is any `5xx` code) Apache marks that connection as in an *Error State*. Apache will then not use that connection for a period of time controlled by the `retry` parameter to `ProxyPass`. This defaults to 60 seconds.

This means that unless you change it, once your back-end generates a `5xx` return code, Apache will not send any more request to it for 60 seconds, but will immediately return a 503 to the client browser.

You can change this by setting the `retry` to a lower number. For example, to wait only 5 seconds before re-trying:

```
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/ retry=5
```

Details of this options, and many others, are in the `ProxyPass` documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

Comment: Thanks that did it!  Even searching that exact page for "retry" previously I didn't detect that setting as its as a "BalancerMember" parameter and it is to configure "Connection pool workers" all of which confused the heck out of me.  Thanks!